# File hash: Does it change for same content but in different order?

Tags: file, hash, sha1

Let's say there is a file called `myfile.txt` with the following contents:

> one two three

Another file called `yourfile.txt` with following contents:

> two three one

Will the `SHA-1` hash be the same for both of these files, because the content are same but in different order?

Comment: Warning: SHA-1 is not considered secure. It is possible with some effort to generate an arbitrary file which has the same hash as a target file. It's probably fine just for uploading images that aren't terribly important, but you should be aware of the possibilities.

Comment: @John: Thanks for the tip, but my usage here is about preventing duplicate file to be uploaded. So if someone tries to reproduce the hash, it's just that they cannot upload the file. I would be worried if it was the other way, like the same file can be uploaded with a different hash. Anyway, what would you suggest for a securing hashing? Might be useful for a future use.

Comment: @John: what you describe (finding a file which hashes to a given target) is called a "preimage attack". If you know how to do that for SHA-1, then, by all means, publish it and become famous. Because right now, the best that cryptographers achieve on SHA-1 is a theoretical collision attack (in which there is no predefined "target") which, while being "easier" than a generic attack, is still substantially expensive (it would require thousands of PC for several months).

Comment: @Nirmal: right now, the usual recommendation for secure hashing is SHA-256 or SHA-512. A new standard hash function (codenamed "SHA-3") is currently being chosen through an open competition, which should define SHA-3 by mid-2012.

Comment: @Thomas Pornin: There are a number of partial preimage attacks known. Check out http://portal.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=1429118 for one example.

Comment: @John: yes, I know those results. They operate on a _reduced_ SHA-1, in which 35 of the 80 rounds have been removed. There is a reason why SHA-1 has 80 rounds... A preimage attack on the first 16 rounds is trivial. Add more rounds and it becomes more complex. That article tries to see how many rounds are necessary for security, and it answers: "at least 46". SHA-1 has 80 and is currently safe on that point. Nobody has a clue yet on how to do a preimage attack on SHA-1 (the "full" SHA-1, with 80 rounds) in less than 2^160 work (which is ludicrous).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it'll be different. Most good general purpose hashing algorithms take order into account. About the only commonly used hash functions that don't are simple checksums.

Answer (score 2):

No, it will be different.  Hashes typically work iteratively over a series of bytes.

Of course, you could just try it ;)

Comment: Yeah, I could try it, but I am on a customer's machine now and a sudden doubt popped up in parallel :)

Answer (score 2):

Depends on the hash algorithm. I can create one right now that returns two equal hashes for both files.

But since you specifically asked about SHA-1 then yes, they will be completely different.

```
    SHA1("one two three") = a10600b129253b1aaaa860778bef2043ee40c715
    SHA1("two three one") = 5b836799b259835e762c93964a68b958eb19461a
```

Comment: For a "secure" hash, it would have to be different, or it wouldn't be too secure.  For any old hash, you could create whatever you wanted.

Comment: If I create one now by definition it can't be "old", can it? :) Anyways yes of course, any serious hash algorithm will produce different results.

Comment: My main reason for asking this is to prevent users from uploading the same file twice at any point. But suddenly wondered what would happen if the contents just swap. Now with the results, my Sunday is saved!

Answer (score 2):

'Cryptographic' hashes are designed to detect changes like transpositions, otherwise someone could take an electronic payment message and change the $1900.00 amount to $9100.00 without detection (by the hash anyway), which would kind of defeat the purpose.